# Use Isotope And Use The Desired Design (Masonary Design)

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry, jquery-isotope

How to use the existing or [masonary](https://masonry.desandro.com) design when an [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co) are also integrate.

The design that I want to use is a having a **Masonary**, cascading grid layout library to make every thing responsive even though it contain different text but I need to add **Isotope**, filter & sort magical layouts, to easily filter desired output.

When I remove the `id="posts"` I got my desired design but the filtering are not functioning. When I add the `id="posts"` the filtering are functioning but the design are full row.

Desired design occurred but isotope not functioning:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigation").load("ajax/navigation2.php");
    $(".footer").load("ajax/footer.html");

    /* activate jquery isotope */
    var $container = $('#posts').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });

    $(window).smartresize(function() {
        $container.isotope({
            columnWidth: '.col-sm-3'
        });
    });

    $container.isotope({ filter: '*' });

    // filter items on button click
    $('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Quicksand');

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.masonry {
    display: block;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2.25rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 2.25rem;
    column-gap: 12.25rem;
}

.masonry.masonry-columns-5 {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}

@media(max-width: 1170px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5 {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}


.masonry.masonry-columns-4 {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
.masonry.masonry-columns-3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}


.masonry.masonry-columns-2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}

.masonry.masonry-columns-1 {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
}



@media(max-width: 991px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-4,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5 {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-4,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-3 {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 540px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-4,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-3,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-2 {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

.masonry .masonry-item {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    float: none !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 2.25rem !important;
}

.masonry .masonry-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.masonry .masonry-item:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .post-title {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .post-info {
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.masonry .masonry-item p {
    color: #666;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .read-more {
    color: #27c2aa;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .tag-comment {
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #999;
}

/* Isotope Transitions
------------------------------- */

.isotope,
.isotope .item {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -ms-transition-property: height, width;
    -o-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
    -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/1.5.25/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb" style="background-color: transparent;">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.location='#'">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Ask</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1>Ask</h1>
            </div>

                <div id="filters" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 button-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-filter="*">ALL FAQ</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-filter=".web">WEB</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-filter=".design">DESIGN</button>
                </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h3>Find answers to some of our most frequently asked questions</h3>
                <hr width="50%">
            </div>
            <!-- Masonary Content FAQ-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="masonry masonry-columns-3">
                    <div class="masonry-item web item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">Getting Bootstrap Tabs to Play Nice with Masonry</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>This is my template for using Masonry 3 with Bootusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrstrap, Desandro Masonry & Twitter Bootstrap 3. How to use responsive twitter bootstrap & masonry together</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="masonry-item design item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">Bootstrap Masonry</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="masonry-item design item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/550x150" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">Masonry CSS with Bootstrap</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>Bootstrap Masonry example snippets with CSS, Javascript and HTML. ... Example of using CSS only for masonry / isotope style layout with Bootstrap panels.</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="1" class="masonry-item design item">
                        <!-- No Media -->
                        <h2 class="post-title">Masonry with Bootstrap 3</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>In conclusion remember that Masonry was born and remains a JavaScript grid layout library, so even if you can make it work with CSS</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="2" class="masonry-item web  item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">How to create the masonry</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>Getting twitter bootstrap's responsive layout and masonry to play alongside each other is pretty simple.</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="masonry-item web item">
                        <!-- No Media -->
                        <h2 class="post-title">Masonry & Twitter Bootstrap 3</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>For this post I created an example of minimalistic layout for a blog/portfolio using both Bootstrap and Masonry. Why it should be useful?</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

DESIRED DESIGN NOT OCCURRED BUT ISOTOPE FUNCTIONING

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigation").load("ajax/navigation2.php");
    $(".footer").load("ajax/footer.html");

    
    var $container = $('#posts').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });

    $(window).smartresize(function() {
        $container.isotope({
            columnWidth: '.col-sm-3'
        });
    });

    $container.isotope({ filter: '*' });

   
    $('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Quicksand');

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.masonry {
    display: block;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2.25rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 2.25rem;
    column-gap: 12.25rem;
}

.masonry.masonry-columns-5 {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}

@media(max-width: 1170px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5 {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

.masonry.masonry-columns-4 {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}

.masonry.masonry-columns-3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
.masonry.masonry-columns-2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}

.masonry.masonry-columns-1 {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
}


@media(max-width: 991px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-4,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5 {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-4,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-3 {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 540px) {
    .masonry.masonry-columns-4,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-5,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-3,
    .masonry.masonry-columns-2 {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

.masonry .masonry-item {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    float: none !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 2.25rem !important;
}

.masonry .masonry-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.masonry .masonry-item:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .post-title {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .post-info {
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.masonry .masonry-item p {
    color: #666;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .read-more {
    color: #27c2aa;
}

.masonry .masonry-item .tag-comment {
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #999;
}

/* Isotope Transitions
------------------------------- */

.isotope,
.isotope .item {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -ms-transition-property: height, width;
    -o-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
    -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
 
    <!--jquery-1.12.3-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap 3.3.7-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Font-awesome 4.7.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Isotopes-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/1.5.25/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb" style="background-color: transparent;">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.location='#'">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Ask</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1>Ask</h1>
            </div>

                <div id="filters" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 button-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-filter="*">ALL FAQ</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-filter=".web">WEB</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-filter=".design">DESIGN</button>
                </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h3>Find answers to some of our most frequently asked questions</h3>
                <hr width="50%">
            </div>
            <!-- Masonary Content FAQ-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="masonry masonry-columns-3" id="posts">
                    <div class="masonry-item web item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">Getting Bootstrap Tabs to Play Nice with Masonry</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>This is my template for using Masonry 3 with Bootusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrstrap, Desandro Masonry & Twitter Bootstrap 3. How to use responsive twitter bootstrap & masonry together</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="masonry-item design item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">Bootstrap Masonry</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <p>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap, Build a Dynamic Grid with Salvattore and Bootstrap, Masonry with Bootstrap 3, How to create the masonry effects with just bootstrap 3 grid</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="masonry-item design item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/550x150" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">Masonry CSS with Bootstrap</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>Bootstrap Masonry example snippets with CSS, Javascript and HTML. ... Example of using CSS only for masonry / isotope style layout with Bootstrap panels.</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="masonry-item web item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">Build a Dynamic Grid with Bootstrap</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Pusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrosted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>Bootstrap snippet Example of usingusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandrusing Masonry 3 with Bootstrap, Desandr CSS only for masonry / isotope style layout with Bootstrap panels.</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="2" class="masonry-item web  item">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="post-title">How to create the masonry</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>Getting twitter bootstrap's responsive layout and masonry to play alongside each other is pretty simple.</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="masonry-item web item">
                        <!-- No Media -->
                        <h2 class="post-title">Masonry & Twitter Bootstrap 3</h2>
                        <h6 class="post-info">October-8 2015 : Posted by Admin</h6>
                        <p>For this post I created an example of minimalistic layout for a blog/portfolio using both Bootstrap and Masonry. Why it should be useful?</p>
                        <a href="" title="" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                        <div class="tag-comment">
                            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> technology, web</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> no comments</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```